# Ubuntu Server Experiencing Random and Frequent Connection Issues

Tags: networking, server

I recently installed Ubuntu Server 16.04 on an old laptop to use as a small server. The laptop is using a wireless connection setup in /etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlp2s0
iface wlp2s0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.85
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    wpa-ssid network_name
    wpa-psk network_password
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 192.168.0.1
```

network_name and network_password are obviously replaced with the real ones.

Anyways, all other computers on the network will frequently lose connection entirely to the server, but the server laptop continues to have internet. During this time, ping requests are all `From 192.168.0.10 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable`, SFTP does not work, and my music server (Koel) cannot be reached.

The strange part of all this is that if I ping the local IP address of the computer trying to connect to connect from the server, then connection will work without interruption until I cancel the command.

For example, if 192.168.0.10 is trying to ping my laptop server (192.168.0.85), then requests will often fail for long periods of time. Shortly after I run `ping 192.168.0.10` on the server (there is a small delay), all requests will suddenly work (and so will SFTP, SSH, etc).

**Edit:** The issue doesn't occur when configuring the network over ethernet (same IP, same router, etc.).

How can this be fixed (and why is it happening)?

Comment: Does the outgoing ping IP have to be the same as the attempted incoming IP or does simply pinging out (to anywhere) restore the connection? I wonder if the laptop is simply putting the interface to sleep?

Comment: @steeldriver Pinging the gateway IP address fixed the issue in the same way as pinging the incoming IP. I was thinking that the interface may be going into some sort of sleep mode also, but I would not think this would be Ubuntu Server's default option (relatively new install).

Comment: @steeldriver Actually, I was incorrect. I must have coincidentally tried ping at the perfect time last time I attempted this, because pinging the gateway (192.168.0.1) did not do anything this time. This issue continues to confuse me more, the only thing that seems consistent is that pinging the incoming IP always (tested many times over the last week I had Ubuntu Server installed) fixes connection issues while the command is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the answer to this strange issue, or at least the problem.

The fault seems to have been in a terrible Technicolor all-in-one modem (Modem + Router) issued by Time Warner Cable. I recently requested it to be exchanged for another modem due to unrelated issues (frequent internet disconnects) and only then noticed that my server ran without issues.

Luckily they replaced the all-in-one with a somewhat decent modem and router separately, and now these issues (along with many others) have been solved.

If you have strange connection issues over your local network then the router may be the issue.

It has only been about a day or two since the new router, but I am almost entirely sure this was the issue, especially since before I would have to deal with connection issues constantly (and would have noticed them again by now).